# Why do I lose access to a this.state variable in my .then() promise?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create a login and signup process for a react-native mobile app with firebase authentication/database.

I can successfully login with pre existing email/passwords in Login.js.

My problem arises when I attempt to create a new account in SignUp.js

The user is added to firebase authentication correctly but I want my user profiles to have more information. This is why I am writing to the database with their name, email, and other information I have removed from the code on line 33 in Signup.js with the helper function at line 52.

My error is `undefined is not an object(evaluating this.state.email)`, coming from line 33 in SignUp.js

This does not make sense to me as I can create the user successfully on line 27 of SignUp.js using `this.state.email`

Is `this.state.email` going out of scope? Any help is greatly appreciated.

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import * as firebase from 'firebase'; 
import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard';
import Login from './components/Login';
import SignUp from './components/SignUp';

const Application = StackNavigator({
    Login: { screen: Login},
    SignUp: { screen: SignUp},
    Dashboard: { screen: Dashboard },
});

export default class App extends React.Component {
    componentWillMount(){
        const firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: 'MY KEY',
            authDomain: 'MY DOMAIN',
            databaseURL: 'MY DATABASE URL',
        }
        if (!firebase.apps.length) {
            firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Application/>
        )}}
```

Login.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, KeyboardAvoidingView, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements';
import { Input } from './Input';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

export default class Login extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
        }
    }

    loginUser = (email, password, navigate) => {
        try{
            firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then(function(user){
                console.log(user);
                navigate('Dashboard', {email, password});
            })
        }
        catch (error){
            alert('No known user for that email and password combination')
            console.log(error.toString());
        }
    }

    static navigationOptions = { header: null }

    render() {
        const{ navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        return (
            <KeyboardAvoidingView
                behavior='padding'>
                <Input
                    placeholder = 'Email'
                    onChangeText = {email => this.setState({email})}
                    value = {this.state.email}/>
                <Input
                    placeholder = 'Password'
                    secureTextEntry
                    onChangeText = {password => this.setState({password})}
                    value = {this.state.password}/>
                <Button
                    title = 'Log in'
                    onPress = {() => this.loginUser(this.state.email, this.state.password, navigate)}/>
                <Button
                    title = 'Sign up'
                    onPress = {() => navigate('SignUp')}/>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        );
    }
}
```

SignUp.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, KeyboardAvoidingView, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements';
import { Input } from './Input';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard';

import * as firebase from 'firebase';

export default class SignUp extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            email: '',
            password: '',
            confirmPassword: '',
        }
    }

    signUpUser = () => {
        try{
            if(this.state.password === this.state.confirmPassword){
                console.log('CREATING USER...');
                firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).then( response => {
                    console.log('SIGNING IN...');
                    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
                    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
                        if (user) {
                            console.log('WRITING TO DATABASE...');
                            this.writeUserData(user, this.state.email, this.state.firstName, this.state.lastName);
                        }
                        else {
                            alert('Something went wrong. Please try again.');
                            return;
                        }
                    });
                })
            }
            else{
                alert('Passwords do not match');
                return;
            }
        }
        catch(error){
            console.log(error.toString());
        }
    }

    writeUserData = (user, email, first, last) => {
        console.log('ADDING USER ' + user.uid)
        try{
            firebase.database().ref('users/' + user.uid).set({
                email: email,
                first: first,
                last: last,
            });
        }
        catch(error){
            console.log(error.toString());
        }
        console.log('WRITE COMPLETE')
        //navigate to dashboard
    }

    static navigationOptions = { header: null }

    render() {
        const{ navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        return (
            <KeyboardAvoidingView
                behavior='padding'>
                <Input
                   placeholder = 'First Name'
                   onChangeText = {firstName => this.setState({firstName})}
                   value = {this.state.firstName}/>
                <Input
                    placeholder = 'Last Name'
                    onChangeText = {lastName => this.setState({lastName})}
                    value = {this.state.lastName}/>
                <Input
                    placeholder = 'Email'
                    onChangeText = {email => this.setState({email})}
                    value = {this.state.email}/>
                <Input
                    placeholder = 'Password'
                    secureTextEntry
                    onChangeText = {password => this.setState({password})}
                    value = {this.state.password}/>
                <Input
                    placeholder = 'Confirm password'
                    secureTextEntry
                    onChangeText = {confirmPassword => this.setState({confirmPassword})}
                    value = {this.state.confirmPassword}/>

                <Button
                    title = 'Create Account'
                    onPress = {() => this.signUpUser()}/>
                <Text
                    activeOpacity={0.75}
                    onPress = {() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}>
                    Go back
                </Text>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work with an arrow function?  (i.e. change `function(user)` to `user =>`) Anonymous functions do weird things with scope sometimes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`this` changes meaning when it is in a different function. This is basically why object methods work in Javascript, because `this` always refers to the class containing it. When you use `this` in an anonymous function, like you do in your `SignUp.js` file, you are not using the same `this` as before.

A simple workaround is to add a line like:

```
let self = this;
```

Or, if you only need the state:

```
let state = this.state;
```

*Before* the `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {` bit. Then inside, you use the variable you created instead of `this`.

---

Another thing to try is to change your anonymous `function` into an arrow function. Arrow functions do not modify the `this` variable. So, something like:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. If i were to use `let state = this.state` how would I call `writeUserData()`, that function is giving an undefined error.

Comment: Disregard previous comment, your "another thing" worked perfectly. thanks again.

Comment: @DavidOwens Ah, sorry. If you in fact need more variables from the original `this` object, it is better to use the first variant. Then `this.state` would become `self.state` and `this.writeUserData` would become `self.writeUserData`. Or change the anonymous function to an arrow function, which is the simpler solution.

Comment: This is a very common issue in React and React Native. You will become a great sleuth soon enough. The trick is to start thinking immediately about what `this` might be referring to when you see errors about `cannot ___ of undefined` when you expect it to be defined.

Comment: So, if I'm following this correctly, the reason it was `undefined` was because the function itself had no `state` variables? When I tried to access `this.state.email` there was no `email` in the anonymous functions `state`? Correct?

Comment: @DavidOwens Yes! When you use an anonymous `function`, inside it `this` actually refers to the function itself. A default Javascript function has no `state` variable.

Comment: Learn something new everyday! Thanks @AurelBílý

Answer (score 0):

Try using a normal javascript function for the call back rather than the ES6 fat arrow. 
so instead of

`response => {...}`

use

`function(response){...}`

[this article](https://pointdeveloper.com/es6-for-beginners-es6-arrow-functions-and-scope/) may be able to help you understand the scope of the fat arrow function more.

Comment: Arrow functions *do not* change `this`, unlike regular functions. OP says the error shows on line 33 of `SignUp.js`, meaning line 27, inside the arrow function, works fine. You are not solving the problem, but introducing another scope.